# How to retrive the the table td value using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to get the value "Tokyo" in below table. 
https://jsfiddle.net/829qjjsw/

My javascript is

```
var MyRows = jQuery('gv-field-1-10').find('td').text();
alert(MyRows);
```

But it does not work.

Comment: you missing jquery in your fiddle it should work by adding `#` for id or `.` for class check this https://jsfiddle.net/829qjjsw/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to put the dot before the name of the class. This should work:

`var MyRows = jQuery('.gv-field-1-10').find('td').text();`